# Put two submit button at same place

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

is there any way to put two submit button at same position?Since I have submit button with hidden attribute based on dropdown,it will show up desirable button upon selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to achieve something like this?

The main thing you need to look at, is that each button is positioned absolutely and has the same left and right.

```js
var button1El = document.getElementById("button1");
var button2El = document.getElementById("button2");
button1El.addEventListener("click",function() {
    this.style.display="none";
    button2El.style.display = "block";
})
button2El.addEventListener("click",function() {
    this.style.display="none";
    button1El.style.display = "block";
})
```

```css
button{
  position:absolute;
  left:10px;
  top:10px;
}
#button2{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<button id="button1">Button 1</button>
<button id="button2">Button 2</button>
```